# Cannot compile program in Monodevelop

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, mono, monodevelop, monogame

I have been trying for days to fix this problem.

I set up monodevelop 7.8.4 on linux, everything works fine except building.

Whenever I build, it outputs 'build successful' yet no files are changed.

Oddly, I can build it via msbuild.  However I want to be able to build it using the editor.

Comment: You need to compile MonoDevelop 8.x from source code.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try that

Comment: You have to compile from dotdevelop repo, as monodevelop repo won't work https://github.com/lextm/dotdevelop/actions/runs/470983950/workflow

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try that and let you know if it works!